# Can I use a Dimmer switch or Ceiling fan speed switch to control wall panel heater?

Tags: switches

Retired Civil Engineer here. Please answer so I can understand :)
I want to heat a small new bedroom in a converted garage with a 400 watt wall panel heater (resistance heat).  Can I plug it into a new outlet controlled by either a wall dimmer switch or a fan speed control switch to cut down the heat output when needed? Is this a fire hazard?  I know I can use a plug in thermostat outlet for the heater, but am looking at alternatives.

Comment: The heater is probably an inductive load, and that's probably just one thing that makes it different.  But it's not about rating -- it's about safety!  You want it over-designed, over-engineered, double-checked, insured by a corporation, tested and certified by appropriate agencies, etc.  If it's your backyard kiln, who cares, but when it's your house, I'm sure that you can understand, being an Engineer, that the due diligence must necessarily be much more due diligent.

Comment: And the purpose that you put a device operating under, should be a purpose for which it was both designed and rated (and insured). If you burn your house down by doing this, you certainly can't sue anybody to recover any damages.

Comment: There is a good possibility that you can find something like a light dimmer with a sufficient power rating. Finding something that will mount like an outlet may be more difficult. It is probably going to be too large for a switch box.

Comment: I don't think they are designed or intended for that purpose (to control heaters). Don't they have ratings written on them?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the heater to be inductive. It would be resistive.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is most likely not safe.  A dimmer switch is typically going to be designed for small loads only.  Also it is most likely a code violation: https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=118.0.

Comment: I was thinking it was no worse than a chandelier. They can easily use 400 watts with incandescent bulbs. Wondering if a resistance heater acts differently than light bulbs.

Comment: I suppose the duration of the load is different, however.  Does this matter for the switch?

Comment: The code citation seems to address the issue of plugging in an appliance that should not be dimmed, such as an old radio.

Comment: You can get controllers from ebays etc that should be suitably rated. For heaters a thermostat is normally used, so why the use of a dimmer?

Answer (score 0):

Let me add one more aspect: The light dimmer or ceiling fan controller are using SCR (Silicon Controlled Rectifier) (triac) in phase control mode. The SCR is triggered with a phase shift after zero crossing and conducts until next zero crossing. The cycle repeats 100x or 120s per second (AC frequency 50Hz or 60Hz). This is important for a light (not flickering) or motor (not creating excessive acoustic noise). However, this switching mode creates a lot of EMI noise.

Now take into account your baseboard heater: A thermal load has relatively long time constant and doesn't need fast switching. It is also a long and relatively effective antenna making the EMI noise concern even bigger.

A good heater controller design should cycle through complete AC periods, use zero crossing switching for both on and off and that is possible since slower PWM doesn't negatively affect the performance.

I would recommend to look for a well designed, safe controller that would also not pollute the frequency spectrum.

Your additional benefits may be features like timer or temperature control so your bill won't go over the roof if you forget the heater on.

Comment: The heater is a plug in model, so I am wanting to control the receptacle. It came with a thermostat which plugs into the outlet, then you plug the heater into the thermostat`s receptacle.